# Populate magento 1.9 database with more users and orders

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento1.9.3

I really need to know if there is a tool to help me generate more than the available 20 users and 40 orders. The module that I am developing requires much more data than what is provided in the sample data. I have tried searching google and GitHub for half a day now with no results. Any tips are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most comprehensive tool for this purpose for Magento 1 is Magento Performance Toolkit:

https://github.com/magento/magento-performance-toolkit

Tool was written for Magento EE, but as far as I see, someone created PR which allows using it for your Magento version:

https://github.com/magento/magento-performance-toolkit/pull/3